# Keyboard options for FileUpload in IE differnt from Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, internet-explorer

I am using Apache's File Upload. Key board "tab" and then "enter" on the Browse button of File Upload does not open an option to browse in IE, but submits the form. But the space bar works fine. In firefox, it works fine, with "enter" it opens an option to browse.
Can anyone plesae let me know why does this happen? Or am I supposed to specify any atrributes for the key board options to work fine?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a difference in the way the two browsers implement the `<input type="file">` HTML tag. I don't think there's any HTML attribute which will override this behaviour, unfortunately.